# draw lines on coordinates retrieve from mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw a line from this location to another location show in the map. I have already retrieve out the coordinates and put a marker for each location but how do i draw a line connecting them ? I have the code though but think i used it wrongly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
//create the markers    
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $location['locationOne']; ?>,
            map: map,
            title: "First location"
        });
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $location['locationTwo']; ?>,
            map: map,
            title: "Second location"
        });
        var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $location['locationThree']; ?>,
            map: map,
            title: "Third location"
        });
        var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $location['locationFour']; ?>,
            map: map,
            title: "Fourth location"
        });
        var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $location['locationFive']; ?>,
            map: map,
            title: "Fifth location"
        });
```

This is the code i'm confused of how to add. Tried a few times but its not working:

```
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map, 
        path: [<?php echo $location['locationOne']; ?>, <?php echo $location['locationTwo']; ?>, <?php echo $location['locationThree']; ?>, <?php echo $location['locationFour']; ?>, <?php echo $location['locationFive']; ?>],
        strokeWeight: 7,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeColor: "#000000"
    });
```

Comment: Can you post also the exact JavaScript that your browser receives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in coordinate pairs instead of `LatLngs` to the path option.  You need to create a new `LatLng` object (i.e., `new google.maps.LatLng(...)`) for each coordinate pair.  As follows:

```
    path: new google.maps.LatLng([<?php echo $location['locationOne']; ?>), new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $location['locationTwo']; ?>), ...,
```

BTW, are you outputting the $location['locationXXX'] variable with the parentheses? I presume you are.

Comment: btw there's a little error i found.. The bracket([) should be place before new instead of before the php start tag.. thanks for the solution :D